# Django Rest Framework can't register route

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have the following code:

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'mymodel', views.MyModelViewSet, 'mymodel')

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And the following ViewSet:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (OnlyStaffCanPost,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

When I'm trying to access `http://localhost:8000/api/mymodel/` it gives me Not Found error. I printed out `router.urls`, the output is:

```
[<URLPattern '^$' [name='api-root']>, <URLPattern '^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='api-root']>]
```

Why my viewset doesn't get registered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ViewSet does not provide any actions by default
If you want to use CRUD for this model you should use ModelViewSet instead of it like this:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (OnlyStaffCanPost,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

**viewsets.ViewSet -> viewsets.ModelViewSet**

Or if you want only one action you can use mixins like this:

```
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyModelViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = (OnlyStaffCanPost,)
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Comment: I've misinterpreted ViewSet. I thought I'm using ModelViewSet, Thank you.